# Accessing map values from neo4, apoc, Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am still rather new to Neo4j, Cypher and programming in general.

Is there a way to access the posted output below, i.e. access the "count" values for every "item“ (which has to be the pair), and also access the "item" values? I need the amount of how often a pair, i.e. specific neighboring nodes occur not only as information, but as values with which I can further work with in order to adjust my graph.

My last lines of code (in the preceding lines I just ordered the nodes sequentially):

```
...

WITH apoc.coll.pairs(a) as pairsOfa

WITH apoc.coll.frequencies(pairsOfa) AS giveBackFrequencyOfPairsOfa

UNWIND giveBackFrequencyOfPairsOfa AS x 

WITH DISTINCT x

RETURN x
```

Output from the Neo4j Browser that I need to work with:

```
"x"            


│{"count":1,"item":[{"aName“:"Rob","time":1},{"aName":"Edwin“,"time“:2}]},{„count“:4,“item":[{"aName":"Edwin","time":2},{"aName“:"Celesta","time":3}]} 

...
```

Comment: Your description is a little confusing. Can you provide an example of desired output with some additional context?

Comment: Thank you, cybersam solved it below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, your result should contain multiple `x` records (not a single record, as implied by the "output" provided in your question). Here is an example of what I would expect:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"x"                                                                   │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"count":1,"item":[{"aName":"Rob","time":1},{"aName":"Edwin","time":2}│
│]}                                                                    │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"count":1,"item":[{"aName":"Edwin","time":2},{"aName":"Celesta","time│
│":3}]}                                                                │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If that is true, then you can just access the `count` and `item` properties of each `x` directly via `x.count` and `x.item`. To get each value within an item, you could use `x.item[0]` and `x.item[1]`.

*Asides: you probably want to use `apoc.coll.pairsMin` instead of `apoc.coll.pairs`, to avoid the generation of a spurious "pair" (whose second element is `null`) when the number of values to be paired is odd. Also, you probably do not need the `DISTINCT` step.*

Comment: Thank you so very much! It is working. Such a simple solution that I just could not see yet. Now I can work from here :)

Comment: Any chance you could help improve the OP's question?  It's difficult to see this Q/A as very helpful to many others.

Comment: The question was really about the output - how to access "count" and "item" in the output; the output as was correctly given in cybersam's post.